# Data Access JS functions

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, javascript-framework

I have couple of Js functions say `fn1()`, `fn2()`.
`fn1()` would be called automatically when the page loads

```
<script >

window.onload=fn1();

 function fn1()
 {
  var list_temp=new Array();
  list_temp.push("testing");
  //etc
 }

 function fn2()
 {
   // Do something after getting the data from fn1()
 }
 </script>`
```

Now I need to access the list defined in `fn1()` from `fn2()`. Is there anyway that could be done? I remember reading somewhere that functions in Javascript are in a way equivalent to objects?

Comment: FYI `window.onload=fn1()` is saying to set the value of window.onload to what `fn1()` returns; instead, you want `window.onload=fn1` or an anonymous function calling fn1 `window.onload=function(){fn1();}`.

Comment: Interesting, Thanks @Snuffleupagus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a variable in the global scope, but you can also wrap your two functions in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Emulating_private_methods_with_closures) and make the variable private (local) to that closure:

```
(function() {
   var list_temp = [];
   window.onload = fn1;

   function fn1()
   {
       list_temp.push("testing");
       // etc...
   }

   function fn2()
   {
       console && console.log(list_temp);
       // Do something after getting the data from fn1()...
   }
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

simply declare

```
var list_temp=new Array();
```

before

```
function fn1 ()
```

on the same level of

```
window.onload
```

vars declared at top level script are globals ...
In JS var scope is the function ...

Comment: But of course! Thank you. 
Just out of curiosity, would it be possible to get the data declared in one <script></script> declaration from another?

Comment: yep if it load before where you want to use the var !

Comment: Every script is executed in the same *global* scope, so yes.

Answer (score 2):

> `window.onload=fn1();`

That doesn't run `fn1` when the page loads. That runs `fn1` ***immediately*** and assigns its return value to `window.onload`. Exactly like `x = foo();`.

> Now I need to access the list defined in fn1() from fn2(). Is there anyway that could be done?

No, not as defined. `list_temp` is a local within `fn1`. Unless you put it somewhere that `fn2` can access it (some shared scope), `fn2` can't access it.

Here's an example of shared scope (and fixing the `window.onload` thing):

```
(function() {
    var list_temp=new Array(); // Or better, var list_temp = [];

    window.onload=fn1; // No () at end

    function fn1()
    {
        list_temp.push("testing");
        //etc
    }

    function fn2()
    {
        // Do something after getting the data from fn1()
    }
})();
```

Or, of course, you could make `list_temp` global. But that's not generally a good idea.

Comment: What's so bad about global variables in javascript?

Comment: @Wex, modularity. Javascript these days is all about mixing modules (just have a look at all the jQuery conflicts questions around here), so it makes sense to encapsulate as much as you can.

Comment: @Wex: In computer science, global variables are a well-known anti-pattern, just generally. But in particular in browsers, the global namespace is *incredibly* crowded. Suppose you have a `div` with the `id` `"foo"` and, completely separately, you have a global variable called `foo`. Guess what: They conflict with each other, because all `id` values get dumped in the global namespace (as properties pointing to the elements with that `id`).

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the functions together:

```
function fn1()
{
 var list_temp=new Array();
 list_temp.push("testing");
 //etc
 fn2(list_temp);
}

function fn2(data)
{
  // Do something after getting the data from fn1()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I remember reading somewhere that functions in javascript are in a way equivalent to objects?

Yes, all functions are objects, inheriting from a common Function prototoype. And you can set your own properties on them as on all objects, but that won't help us here.

> Now I need to access the list defined in fn1() from fn2()

You can't. The variable declaration of `list_temp` is scoped to the function, it is not available from outside. So you could either

- move the variable declaration in a scope where it is visible to fn2
- export the list object to some other variable that is visible to fn2. The easiest way would be using the `return` statement, for example.